# PHP minus symbol in URL (rawurlencode vs urlencode)

Tags: php, pretty-urls

I've tried using rawurlencode and urlencode, both give me "&" and the other "+".

What i'm asking is, is there a PHP function that puts "-" in between words, like on Stack Overflow?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I understand neither part of your question and what they have to do with each other. Can you clarify?

Comment: might be a `string_replace(' ','-',$url)`

Comment: OP just wants to shoot two ducks with one bullet :D

Comment: $url = 'your url here'; $url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url); .. that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thats all you're trying to do, you could just use:

```
    $url = str_replace(" ", "-", $url);
```

And then use `urlencode` to encode it after that. E.G.:

```
    function myurlencode($url)
    {
        return urlencode(str_replace(" ", "-", $url));
    }
```

**EDIT**

And according to the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), it replaces `all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.  with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.`

Answer (score 0):

`rawurlencode` and `urlencode` are for making URL's the correct format. If you want to replace spaces for dashes you need to use `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(" ", "-", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace a class of characters with another, use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

For example:

```
$newURL = str_replace(" ", "-", $oldURL);
```

would do what you want

[urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is a very specific set of character replacements, which follow the standard for url encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as mentioned `url_encode` is independent from making URLs from text ie to make them SEO-friendly. Usually this is called slugify an url. I guess this is generally what you're looking for, right?

Here is an example of such a method http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php